# NASA CAPSTONE Radiation shielding

Tags: the-moon, nasa, radiation, shielding, capstone

What solutions in radiation shielding or radiation effect mitigation were made on the NASA CAPSTONE mission? Specifically, anything related to radiation shielding is of interest.

I'm having trouble finding anything on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

### None

I'm going to suggest that there is no radiation shielding on CAPSTONE. As an unmanned, 25 kilogram satellite, there's not a need or mass budget for dedicated shielding.

### Tolerance and Hardening

They almost certainly used some kind of [radiation hardening](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50470/what-makes-insights-rad750-processor-so-radiation-resistant-compared-to-1998) for the electronics, and designed the systems for [redundancy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36023/did-the-ibm-system-4-pi-computer-have-radiation-hardened-versions-for-skylab-and) in the event of a radiation induced error, but I didn't find anything regarding those actions during a brief Google search.

### Digging Deeper

It looks like Advanced Space subcontracted out the electronics and coding to [Terran Orbital](https://terranorbital.com/missions/capstone/) - you might poke around their website to see if they list specs for the electronics. It is possible that they consider the details proprietary or not interesting to the public, and in either of those cases they may not have published the data. I didn't find the specs, but I didn't look too hard.